# DDD | Can I import aggregate id (like a ProductId) from another bounded context?

Tags: python, domain-driven-design

I have aggregates `ExampleEntity1` with `ExampleEntity1ID` and `ExampleEntity2` with `ExampleEntity2ID`. `ExampleEntity2` refers to `ExampleEntity1` by using `ExampleEntity1ID`. `ExampleEntity1` and `ExampleEntity2` are in different bounded contexts. Can I in this situation import `ExampleEntity1ID` from first context in second context or I should redefine `ExampleEntity1ID` in second context? What should I do if I need to use same id into 2 different contexts?

---

Example:
*/domain/context_1/models.py*

```py
class ExampleEntity1ID:
    value: str

class ExampleEntity1:
    id: ExampleEntity1ID
    some_field_1: str
```

*/domain/context_2/models.py*

```py
from domain.context_1 import ExampleEntity1ID

class ExampleEntity2ID:
    value: str

class ExampleEntity2:
    id: ExampleEntity2ID
    example_entity_1_id: ExampleEntity1ID
    some_field_2: str
```

or redefine it

```py
class ExampleEntity1ID:
    value: str

class ExampleEntity2ID:
    value: str

class ExampleEntity2:
    id: ExampleEntity2ID
    example_entity_1_id: ExampleEntity1ID
    some_field_2: str
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider repeating yourself (**breaking DRY** is the lesser evil here!). First of all, referencing other bounded contexts is not recommended at all. In the worst situation, you should make a shared kernel to reuse structures between bounded contexts. However, you won't need that in this example. Because the possibility of changing the ID representation of an entity is low. So in my humble opinion rewriting the structure would be better. On the other hand, changing the ID is something that needs to be done with care and coordination with other teams. As a result, the change is so bold that you won't miss changing the duplicated code (the problem that DRY wants to solve).

Comment: In general, I've come to the same conclusion. By the way, what do you think are some good reasons to use a specific ID for each aggregate rather than just a UUID (or int)? I've heard many times that this is a good practice, but I haven't found any serious advantages to this approach yet

Comment: Because the ID might be a complex type. It might have behavior.